# Fetching and caching the result in Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

My application uses **select2** to show list of names which is retrieved through Ajax call.
It uses select2 ajax functionalities.

But the problem is that **select2** fetches items whenever i type on the **select2** input. 
I dont want to fetch every time user type. I want to fetch items in the initial loading of **select2** and then uses same data even if they typing in the select2 input.

How can i achieve this?

PS: I have seen cache flag in Ajax, but i think it does caching the result based on the URL. 
    It does not stop fetching of data when user type on the select2 input.

Comment: Probably easier to put all available options inside a `<select>` and use the non-ajax version I'd say.

Comment: For what it's worth, here's the select2 answer: https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/110

Comment: Updated link for codecraig comment: https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/110

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Select2 load data using ajax with caching in-place.

```
$("#selIUT").select2({
            cacheDataSource: [],
            placeholder: "Please enter the name",
            query: function(query) {
                self = this;
                var key = query.term;
                var cachedData = self.cacheDataSource[key];

                if(cachedData) {
                    query.callback({results: cachedData.result});
                    return;
                } else {
                    $.ajax({
                      url: '/ajax/suggest/',
                      data: { q : query.term },
                      dataType: 'json',
                      type: 'GET',
                      success: function(data) {
                        self.cacheDataSource[key] = data;
                        query.callback({results: data.result});
                      }
                    })
                }
            },
            width: '250px',
            formatResult: formatResult, 
            formatSelection: formatSelection, 
            dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop", 
            escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; } 
        });
```

I hope you find it helpful.

Comment: Actually you need to replace query.callback({results: data.result}); with query.callback({results: data}); and query.callback({results: cachedData.result}) with query.callback({results: cachedData})

Comment: coorasse , 
I'm adding data.result because my data is in "result" variable.
If you are directly returning your result in "data" variable then you code will also work.

Answer (score 1):

I got caching to work with paging.

```
query: function (query) {
    var id = this.element[0].id;
    var term = query.term;
    var total = 100;

    if (!window.select2cache[id]) {
        window.select2cache[id] = {};
    }
    if (!window.select2cache[id][term]) {
        window.select2cache[id][term] = {
            results: {
                results: [],
                more: false
            },
            pages: 0
        };
    }


    if (window.select2cache[id][term].pages > 0 && query.page === 1) {
        query.callback(window.select2cache[id][term].results);
    } else {
        var page = window.select2cache[id][term].pages + 1;
        var vars = {
            task: id,
            q: term,
            page: page,
            total: total
        };
        $.get("./autocomplete.php", vars, function (data) {
            var more = (page * total) < data.totalrows;
            window.select2cache[id][term].results.results = window.select2cache[id][term].results.results.concat(data.results);
            window.select2cache[id][term].results.more = more;
            window.select2cache[id][term].pages = page;
            query.callback({results: data.results, more: more});
        }, "json");
    }
}
```

I use the `id` so you can have multiple select2's on the same page and cache them seperately.